# Error reg proper XML file Implementation while trying to display JSON data from URL

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to display JSON data from a URL as a list in which each row has 9 features. I am getting " Unfortunately project_name has stopped working" Error. After looking on the net, I found out that I probably have an error in the implementation of my xml files.

I am using the following listview

```
 ListView lv=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

and a simple adapter method

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { StyleId,productId,brandName,productName,thumbnailImageUrl,originalPrice,price,
                     percentOff, productUrl }, 
                     new int[] {
                     R.id.styleId, R.id.productId, R.id.brandName, R.id.productName,R.id.thumbnailImageUrl,R.id.originalPrice,R.id.price,R.id.percentOff,R.id.productUrl }
                                       );
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My XML files are as follows:-

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout


 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView  android:id="@+id/styleId" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?        android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
<TextView  android:id="@+id/productId" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>    
<TextView  android:id="@+id/brandName" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>    
<TextView  android:id="@+id/productName" android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>    
<TextView  android:id="@+id/thumbnailImageUrl" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>        
<TextView  android:id="@+id/originalPrice" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>    
<TextView  android:id="@+id/price" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">  </TextView>    
<TextView  android:id="@+id/percentOff" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>    
<TextView  android:id="@+id/productUrl" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>    


 </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me on this.

Log:

```
02-23 04:30:46.874: I/Choreographer(1251): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

02-23 04:30:46.964: I/Choreographer(1251): Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

02-23 04:30:47.044: I/Choreographer(1251): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

02-23 04:30:47.284: D/dalvikvm(2012): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)

02-23 04:30:54.224: W/ActivityManager(1251): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

02-23 04:30:54.244: E/WindowManager(1251): Starting window AppWindowToken{b45b25f8 token=Token{b42197c0 ActivityRecord{b4219660 u0 com.example.zappos/.MainActivity t6}}} timed out

02-23 04:31:29.464: D/AndroidRuntime(2012): Shutting down VM

02-23 04:31:29.464: W/dalvikvm(2012): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3cc0b08)

02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): Process: com.example.zappos, PID: 2012

02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zappos/com.example.zappos.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1883)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.example.zappos.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:41)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
02-23 04:31:31.794: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     ... 11 more
02-23 04:31:31.804: W/ActivityManager(1251):   Force finishing activity com.example.zappos/.MainActivity
```

Comment: what error you got .can you show your error logs here..

Answer (score 0):

1st thing: There is a **nullpointerexception** in your program. Try to find out this. I think you did all your network stuff in main thread. if so then make it in separate thread or use [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

2nd thing: You missed to give  layoutheight in the 1st textview of your custom layout.i.e something like this:

```
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/styleId"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
       </TextView>
```

3rd thing: please amke sure tht your jsonlist is not empty with some log and use it inside if else clause which will protect you from nullpointer if it is empty through esle part.

4th thing: I thing you are testing the application through emulator. i guess by `Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`  warning. this warning comes in emulator maximum times because for slow processing. If so then please check your localhost address that it is [10.0.2.2](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) .

you also can use ArrayAdapter instead of List.

These are my possible suggestions without seeing total code and json parsing. hope these will help you to find out the problem.